# Facebook Timeline Database?

Tags: mysql, facebook, cassandra

I was reading an article about facebook timeline https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150468255628920

I always thought this kind of core produces would prefer Cassandra. However it is using MySQL/InnoDB.

Could anyone briefly explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Available internal / external expertise with MySQL (it's easier to google solutions for existing problems)
2. Cassandra is much harder to reason about due to eventual consistency and limited transaction support
3. Moving to a new datastore is a lot of pain and it doesn't seem to be justified

You can check out the slides below for their usecases:

- [MySQL at Facebook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zofzid6xIZ4#t=04m10s)
- [Scale at Facebook](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Scale-at-Facebook)

Comment: That article also talked about TimeLine ranking. Is that just sorting by time or anything else ?  Thanks

Comment: I guess that refers to their algorithm of shuffling posts on user's timeline so that the most important / interesting are on top.